# How to increase quantity of file descriptors on MacOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

Can't find a way to do this, every version of MacOS use a different version and Mojave still very recent, so can't find anything.

Comment: In what context? What are you trying to do that you need more file descriptors? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I'm getting random errors during a load test of a application that access a database. Trying to exclude the things that can be a problem.

Comment: The error was another thing, more details [here](https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/805), but the question about how to increase the file descriptors still valid.

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically, you can use `getrlimit()` and `setrlimit()` to adjust the number of file descriptors the process can open. The relevant resource identifier is `RLIMIT_NOFILE`.

As noted in the man page, `RLIMIT_NOFILE` works somewhat differently than other resources. `getrlimit()` might indicate that the hard limit is `RLIM_INFINITY` (unlimited), but the kernel actually imposes a limit of `OPEN_MAX` (currently 10240). So, treat that as the maximum that you can set using `setrlimit()`.

To do this for a program whose code you don't control, you can adjust the limit in a shell before launching that program from that shell. In `bash` and other `sh`-derived shells, you can use the `ulimit` built-in command for that. For example, `ulimit -Sn 10240`.